# how to translate HEX values into X Y Z

Tags: hex

I am trying to understand how an application I have been using is setting its data in XYZ coordinates which I wish to convert to HEX value. The application essentially shows me the XYZ in one format (float maybe), but I am only able to edit this data in HEX, so I need to understand the translation to make proper edits.

First off lets look at the values displayed in the program

**X = 1.085597
Y = 4.703604
Z = -17.573305**

The HEX values for these XYZ values is 12 bytes, which I assume is 4 bytes for X values, 4 for Y, and for for Z. Here is the HEX output:

**19 B3 87 44 D6 FC 92 45 9C 4A 89 C6**

So what I am wondering is if there is a way to ascertain (from the data I have provided) the formula that the application is using so I can convert the XYZ values to HEX values?

Someone metioned it might be [IEEE 754 standard?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) but I'm new to hex editing so I'm not sure how to apply this or what it means.

HEX values appear to be in little endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hex you posted is equivant to the float value * 10^3

That is  1085.597 == 0x4487b319 and so on

Use any online calculator to check in both direction  like

https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: thank you so much. I found this site worked too

http://www.scadacore.com/field-tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/